Nanopore sequencing continuation and data merging
I started a run which should last for 72 hours but unfortunately I had power failure and the remaining hours to complete was 31 hours. However, the base calling and bar coding will be done after the run.
Should I start the run for the remaining hours and can I add the reads generated to the previous one?
Or I can go ahead with the base call for the already data generated?

Yes, it's fine to continue Nanopore sequencing runs after a power failure. The run start dialog at the beginning of runs gives you the option of continuing an existing experiment (which keeps the same settings, and stores the results in the same base folder), or you can start from scratch.
When processing the data downstream, I typically combine (concatenate) all the read files from all sub-runs.
If you point the basecaller (e.g. dorado) at the base directory and use recursive mode (-r), then it will handle multiple runs fine.

Thank you for the input.
